# XSLT - Convert Date (YYYY-MM-DD) to Julian Day Number

Tags: xml, date, xslt, xslt-2.0

Attempting to convert a standard date to Julian day number. Is there a function or method that you have used to successfully convert a date? This is for XSLT 2.0. One additional constraint is no additional add-on packages can be used, just straight XSLT 2.0

Thank you in advance for your input.

Example: 2016-07-05 Converts to 2457574.50000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `YYYY-MMM-DD` is not a standard date. You must convert the supplied string to a valid date in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, before you can use any of the date functions. Once you have done that, the calculation can be pretty straightforward.

For convenience, the following stylesheet uses two custom-defined functions: one to convert the string a proper date, and one to calculate the actual Julian day number.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="my:reformat-date">
    <xsl:param name="datestring"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="substring($datestring, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mmm" select="substring($datestring, 6, 3)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring($datestring, 10, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="format-number(index-of(('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'), $mmm), '00')"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="xs:date(concat($y, '-', $m, '-', $d))" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="my:julian-day-number">
    <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:date"/>
    <xsl:variable name="epoch" select="xs:date('-4714-11-24')"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="days-from-duration($date - $epoch)"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="my:julian-day-number(my:reformat-date('2016-JUL-05'))" />
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>2457575</result>
```

---

**Note**:

Strictly speaking, a Julian day number changes at noon. If your input does not indicate the time of the day, the decision whether to select the number for the AM or the PM part of the given date is purely arbitrary.

Comment: Hi Michael - Thank you for your response, this is correct (as marked). Much appreciated. I spoke loosely about the date standard. I'll edit the post to note. I do have one question though, can you please expand on the "+ 1721426" in the Julian function calculation?

Comment: I am glad you asked this, because now I have learned something, too. I thought negative dates were not valid in XML, so I calculated the number of days since the beginning of the proleptic Gregorian calendar, and added the required offset to get the number of days elapsed since November 24, 4714 BC. But I now I see that it can work with the JDN epoch date directly, which makes it even simpler.